# Netmeeting in C#

Tags: c#, .net, telephony

I want to get some of the netmeeting functionality in my C# program. Mainly I want to be able to call a H.323 teleconference system by IP. Google turns up mention of Netmeeting SDK but no download link and it seems that Microsoft has discontinued Netmeeting altogether.

Can someone give a suggestion or a pointer on the best way to go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netmeeting has been retired and replaced by [Live Meeting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/livemeeting/FX101729061033.aspx), [Office Communicator](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator/FX101729051033.aspx), and the [Office Communications Server](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicationsserver/default.aspx). Which is a Very Good Thing, as they by are orders of magnitude more advanced and modern communication tools than Netmeeting (not to mention just plain more reliable). They are also easily interoperable with .NET. The [Live Meeting Service Developer Portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905513.aspx) is a good place to start.